# SQL: Auto insert current date as string/varchar

Tags: sql, datetime, monetdb

I would like to set up a schema which will store the current date as a string fitting in a varchar column of size 10. However CURDATE() returns as a date type, is there any way I can convert this when creating a table to automatically convert this to a string?

For reference I am using MonetDB and declaring the column like below, can I cast CURDATE somehow when creating a table?

```
 tdate     varchar(10)   default  CURDATE()  ,
```

Comment: Why would you store data as string?

Comment: Mihai, the string format is for compatibility with some old code. I am also storing as a date datatype for practical purposes, but the string representation is also necessary for compatibility.

Comment: Maybe use trigger with DATE_FORMAT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

create table dateexample
(
id int identity(1,1),
empname varchar(100),
dateinserted varchar(10) DEFAULT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101))
)

insert into dateexample (empname) 
values
('johny')

select * from dateexample
-- 1    johny   04/24/2014