# How to get datetime as string from mysql database in django model query

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, django-models

I am using below query to get fields from mysql database in django 1.9.

```
event_dict_list = EventsModel.objects.filter(name__icontains = event_name).values('sys_id','name', 'start_date_time', 'end_date_time', 'notes')
```

now in the result `event_dict_list`, `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` are appearing in python date time object format as below

```
'end_date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 26, 10, 48, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

I want it as a string in `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format.

One way would be to iterate over the `event_dict_list` and get date field and then convert it into desired string format. But I wanted to know if there is any way I can specify something in query so that I get the converted date in query output only?

Related question - what is preferred way to store date/datetime in database - as python date time or as string. Way 1 or way 2.
(1) `end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)`
(2) `end_date_time = models.CharField(max_length= 128, null=False, blank=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the CAST() command in your query:
[Convert DateTime Value into String in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql)

The above example kinda shows you how to!

If that doesnt work, the other option is as you stated, iterate over your dates and times and convert as shown here:
[Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)