# 'LIKE%' is not working in update query while comparing datetime in database

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

What i am doing is comparing current date with the 'date' field (which has certain date) in a table 'permanent_days' in MySql database (PhpMyadmin). Data type of that 'date' field is datetime. My source code is as follows:

```
double sum = previous_total + 0.5;
query = "UPDATE permanent_days SET total_days='"+sum+"' WHERE emp_id_fk='"+_ID+"' AND date LIKE '"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM")+"%'";
command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection, transaction);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After i execute this code, i am getting following exception:

> > Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2016-10% for column 'date' at row 1

Note that this comparison works fine while using 'Select' sql command. However, in 'Update' sql command (as mentioned above), this comparisons throws above mentioned exception. What can be the possible solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime Value into String in Mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql)

Comment: The obvious thing to point out is that `LIKE` works on text/char fields and will not work on Date or DateTime fields.

Comment: But LIKE works exactly the same way in SELECT command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert your date time to string, then you can use `LIKE`.

You can use [`Convert()` and `Cast()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html). But better:

```
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '2016-10-%'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392429/4795214)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1-DateTime.Now.Day)?

```
query = "UPDATE permanent_days SET total_days='"+sum;
query += "' WHERE emp_id_fk='"+_ID+"' AND ";
query += "'date >  '"+DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1-DateTime.Now.Day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'";
```

Comment: You'd also have make sure that `date` is less than the last day of the current month.

Comment: @juharr Yes of course. I made assumptions I shouldn't have made.