# phpmyadmin stored procedure: insert not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a procedure in phpmyadmin and when I try to insert a new row, it doesn't work. I'm trying to create a new row in the table "VOTE_TOKEN" if the current date is the same as "LAST_DATE" in the table RESERVATION.  Here is the definition of my procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE date_container_st varchar(15);
DECLARE date_array varchar(15);
DECLARE date_today varchar(15);
DECLARE date_today_array varchar(15);
SELECT OWNER_ID, LOCATING_ID, LAST_DATE   
FROM RESERVATION                                       
WHERE ID = res_id;

SET date_container_st=RESERVATION.LAST_DATE ;
SET date_today=(CHAR(15), GETDATE(), 101);

IF (date_today=RESERVATION.LAST_DATE)
THEN
       INSERT INTO VOTE_TOKEN(TARGET_ID, VOTING_ID, IS_B_OWNER) 
       VALUES(RESERVATION.OWNER_ID, RESERVATION.LOCATING_ID, 0);                       
       INSERT INTO VOTE_TOKEN(TARGET_ID, VOTING_ID, IS_B_OWNER)
       VALUES(RESERVATION.LOCATING_ID, RESERVATION.OWNER_ID, 1);  
END IF;  END
```

When I call this procedure, phpmyadmin only returns a small table containing the "owner_id", "locating_id" and "last_date" and doesn't create any row in the table "VOTE_TOKEN"

Thanks for helping

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? You've tagged `phpmyadmin`, however, PHP MyAdmin doesn't work with SQL Server, so I *suspect* the former.

Comment: since you tagged phpmyadmin, is this a suspected issue with the phpmyadmin software specifically (as opposed to just an issue with a MySQL query), or do you just happen to be using that as your MySQL GUI? If the latter, then this tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Anyway, `SET date_container_st=RESERVATION.LAST_DATE ;` appears to make no sense, and neither does `IF (date_today=RESERVATION.LAST_DATE)`. You can't set a single variable to be, or a compare a variable to, an entire column. Which of the rows in the reservation table are you trying to select? You realise that your SELECT statement doesn't do anything except print to the console? It doesn't affect the later parts of your query. Read up about assigning query results to variables.

Comment: Sorry for the sql-server tag, it was a mishandling

Comment: I want to get the values of "LAST_DATE", "OWNER_ID" and "LOCATING_ID" for the row where the id is "res_id" and insert 2 new rows in "VOTE_TOKEN" with these values. I don't really know how to deal with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not fetch the values returned by the `select` into variables, therefore you cannot work with them. None of your `RESERVATION.xxx` variables exist. You can use the [select ... into ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) statement for assigning values from your query to variables.

```
...
DECLARE V_OWNER_ID bigint;
DECLARE V_LOCATING_ID bigint;
DECLARE V_LAST_DATE date;

SELECT OWNER_ID, LOCATING_ID, LAST_DATE 
INTO V_OWNER_ID, V_LOCATING_ID, V_LAST_DATE  
FROM RESERVATION                                       
WHERE ID = res_id;
...
```

Use the variables `V_*` in your code in place of the `RESERVATION.xxx` variables.

Also, you need to use `curdate()` function to get today's date. You are using an ms sql server version of the code.

However, the ehole code can be simplified as:

```
   INSERT INTO VOTE_TOKEN(TARGET_ID, VOTING_ID, IS_B_OWNER) 
   SELECT RESERVATION.OWNER_ID, RESERVATION.LOCATING_ID, 0
   FROM RESERVATION
   WHERE RESERVATION.ID = res_id AND RESERVATION.LAST_DATE=curdate();                       
   INSERT INTO VOTE_TOKEN(TARGET_ID, VOTING_ID, IS_B_OWNER) 
   SELECT RESERVATION.OWNER_ID, RESERVATION.LOCATING_ID, 1
   FROM RESERVATION
   WHERE RESERVATION.ID = res_id AND RESERVATION.LAST_DATE=curdate();
```

No need for variables and if.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. "LAST_DATE" is stored as a varchar, so how could I convert "curdate()" to a varchar?  Thank you

Comment: You could have googled it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql

Comment: @J.Pelle don't store dates as strings, this is a design flaw in your database