# How to convert datetime to string format in sql query?

Tags: php, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

How to convert `datetime` to string format in SQL query for example just like in PHP there is function of `strtotime()` how can we do that in SQL query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime Value into String in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392413/convert-datetime-value-into-string-in-mysql)

Comment: it's a practice to not apply complex operations in db level (string manipulation) in case you would like to have an agile and responsive backend.

Answer (score 1):

If this oracle sql, you can use to_char (dateValue , formatMask) function. For example,
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') Result: '2003/07/09 12:04:20
' TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'Month DD, YYYY') Result: 'July 09, 2003'